# Is an equivalence an adjunction?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Let $C$ and $D$ be categories and $F:C\to D$, $G:D\to C$ two functors.

$F$ is *left-adjoint* to $G$, if there are natural transformations $\eta:id_C\to GF$ and $\epsilon:FG\to id_D$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
F&\xrightarrow{F\eta}&FGF&\xrightarrow{\epsilon F}F\\
G&\xrightarrow{\eta G}&GFG&\xrightarrow{G\epsilon}G
\end{eqnarray}
are the identity (!) transformations.

$F$ is an *equivalence of categories* (with inverse $G$) if there are natural isomorphisms $\eta:id_C\to GF$ and $\epsilon:FG\to id_D$ without any further properties.

> Is $F$ left-adjoint to $G$, if $F$ is an equivalence of categories (with inverse $G$)?
> If not, suppose that $F$ is an equivalence of categories with inverse $G':D\to C$ and suppose further that $F$ is left-adjoint to $G$. Does it follow that there is a natural isomorphism $G\to G'$ or is there even an identity $G=G'$?

Comment: The answer to the first question is "yes", $F$ is both left-adjoint and right-adjoint to $G$. The answer to the second question is "yes, there exists a natural isomorphism $G\to G'$, but it is not necessarily an identity".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Every equivalence can be "improved" to an adjoint equivalence, but you may have to change the unit or the counit: see e.g. [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+equivalence) for a proof. Essentially the same thing is proved as Theorem 4.2.3 in the Homotopy Type Theory book.

Comment: What is *the* Homotopy Type Theory book?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: it can be characterized as either the unique book with title "Homotopy Type Theory" or as the unique book on the subject of Homotopy Type Theory.

Comment: http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/

Comment: Thanks, Zhen Lin. Does it follow that there is a natural isomorphism $G\cong G'$?

Comment: Adjoints are unique up to unique isomorphism.

Comment: Suppose we have already shown that the natural iso $\eta : 1_{\mathbf{C}} \to GF$ witnessing the equivalence is the unit of the desired adjunction. Why can't the counit just be the other iso $\epsilon : FG \to 1_{\mathbf{D}}$ of the equivalence in general? It satisfies the UMP the counit since for each $g: FC \to D$, we have $\epsilon_D \circ (\epsilon_D^{-1} \circ g) = g$ and $\epsilon_D^{-1} \circ g =  Ff$ for some unique $f : C \to GD$, since we can show that $F$ is fully faithful. What is wrong with this argument?

Comment: Yes, $\epsilon$ is a counit, but not necessarily for the same adjunction.

Comment: Could you develop a little bit more why this argument doesn't proof that it is a counit for the same adjunction? (Is it because it does not show that they are related by the triangle identities?)

Comment: They would have to satisfy the triangle identities if they were unit and counit for the same adjunction.