# Number of ways to describe a unit/counit equivalence.

Tags: category-theory

Given two categories $C$ and $D$ and two fucntors $F:C \to D$ and $G:D \to C$ that form an equivalence. Is it true that there is more than one way to describe the equivalence in terms of a unit and a counit? If so then what can one say about the relationship between the these different units and counits? Is there some type of classifying space?

Comment: You mean $F$ and $G$ form an adjunction?

Comment: Take an easy example: consider the case where both categories are groups considered one-object groupoids. An equivalence of categories here is basically a pair of isomorphisms of groups whose composites are inner automorphisms, and the choice of units is basically the kernel of $G \to \operatorname{Inn} G$.

Comment: I have written some details in the related question of yours: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3891297